# Which is correct: “night shift” or “nightshift”?

Tags: orthography

Which is the correct way, Microsoft word seems to accept both ways but doing a test in English "night shift" was spelled as two separate words in an answer.

Answer (score -2):

According to most dictionaries it's two words.

> night shift or night·shift
>
> 1. A group of employees working during the night in a factory or business.
> 2. The period of time for such work.  [- AHD](https://ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=nightshift)

The American Heritage Dictionary lists both ways already. Why already? A lot of compound words tend to evolve to a one-word word. As the following ngram shows the two word usage is a lot more common and there is no conclusive (decisive) trend towards the one-word version.

[image: nightshift_vs_night_shift]